# Scrolling through "similar questions" resulted in visual tearing/overlap

Tags: bug, design, user-experience, firefox, similar-questions

I started to type a question and when I scrolled through the similar questions box there was some sort of overlapping visual bug:

[image]

Comment: What OS/browser and can you repeat the problem?  I was unable to reproduce in W10 with Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @DanNeely, firefox W10. I have not reproduced it yet.

Comment: @DanNeely I have the same problem, I use Firefox 70.0.1 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Jordan, btw, you can click on  the ^ at the top-right, twice, and it fixes the problem. Just a work around until it gets fixed.

Comment: See [this re-report on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340329/stackoverflow-duplicated-layer-bug), which seems to have attracted the attention of some of the developers.

Comment: @CodyGray cool, thanks for the update!

Comment: I was coming here with the same problem.  Irritating.

Comment: Still here with firefox 81

Comment: Same with Firefox 82.0.2 on Mac OS, and also the latest Firefox version on Ubuntu.

Comment: It seems to occur only after the list of questions is populated for the second time.
Firefox 86.0 (64-bit) on Manjaro with XFCE