# Buggy elevator?

Tags: bug, firefox

While writing questions, I face this little bug with the elevator when I wish to browse for similar ones;

[image: Buggy elevator]

I'm on Firefox (latest; `75.0 (64-bit)` at time of writing) / Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340329/stack-overflow-duplicated-layer-bug

Comment: Indeed, as a comment suggests here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391344/scrolling-through-similar-questions-resulted-in-visual-tearing-overlap clicking twice the little up-arrow `^` at the top right of the component makes the bug disappear. It's a workaround until it gets fixed.